# Flexpaper : License key not accepted error

Tags: html, pdf, flash, flexpaper

Hi I have the licensed Flexpaper product : "FlexPaper_2.2.2_c_customizable_readonly"
I need to render a PDF file in HTML5

The Licenskey is added to the JavaScript call below, but i get a error as "Licence key not accepted (incorrect key). Obtain a licence from http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/"

The key is added to the code as guided in the site http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_publishing_html5.jsp

The code is as below:

```
                $('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer(
              { config : {

                     PDFFile : 'pdf/Paper.pdf',
                     Scale : 0.6, 
                     ZoomTransition : 'easeOut',
                     ZoomTime : 0.5, 
                     ZoomInterval : 0.1,
                     FitPageOnLoad : true,
                     FitWidthOnLoad : false, 
                     FullScreenAsMaxWindow : false,
                     ProgressiveLoading : false,
                     MinZoomSize : 0.2,
                     MaxZoomSize : 5,
                     SearchMatchAll : false,
                     RenderingOrder : 'html5,flash',

                     ViewModeToolsVisible : true,
                     ZoomToolsVisible : true,
                     NavToolsVisible : true,
                     CursorToolsVisible : true,
                     SearchToolsVisible : true,
                     Toolbar         : toolbarData,

                     JSONDataType : 'jsonp',
                     key : '$NINTEEN_CHARACTER_KEY',

                     localeChain: 'en_US'

                     }}
```

Do I need to add the key to the **config.xml** as well ? If yes how ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello i am using flex paper in my project. I have downloaded free version from site. I have setup in my project but i am getting some blank pages in flipbook.

Comment: can u please explain me how to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the website using a sub domain linked to the domain you registered for the serial key. For example if the domain you registered was example.com, it should work on the test.example.com sub domain or any other sub domain (including the root one).

Another thing that could be causing errors is the fact that you have flash in the rendering order but you never point to a SWF file.

Comment: In my case i have pointed to the swf file, but i'm using this within my intranet without the use of the DomainName.com

Comment: What is SWF file and how to set the path to it?

Comment: This was answered a couple of years ago, I would be surprised if the current versions of Flexpaper still used flash since it has been deprecated by most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default config for flexpaper with annotations in html5. Here is the sample parameter passed to flexpaper.

```
$('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer(
              { config : {
                  SWFFile                 : '/upload/Paper.pdf.swf',
                  //IMGFiles              : '/docs/Paper.pdf_{page}.png',
                  //JSONFile              : '/docs/Paper.js',
                  PDFFile                 : '/upload/Paper.pdf',
                  Scale                   : 0.6,
                  ZoomTransition          : 'easeOut',
                  ZoomTime                : 0.5,
                  ZoomInterval            : 0.2,
                  FitPageOnLoad           : true,
                  FitWidthOnLoad          : false,
                  FullScreenAsMaxWindow   : false,
                  ProgressiveLoading      : false,
                  MinZoomSize             : 0.2,
                  MaxZoomSize             : 5,
                  SearchMatchAll          : false,
                  StickyTools             : true,

                  Toolbar                 : toolbardata,
                  BottomToolbar           : '<path to annotations file provided by flexpaper UI_flexpaper_annotations.html>',
                  InitViewMode            : 'Portrait',
                  RenderingOrder          : 'html5,flash',
                  StartAtPage             : '',

                  ViewModeToolsVisible    : true,
                  ZoomToolsVisible        : true,
                  NavToolsVisible         : true,
                  CursorToolsVisible      : true,
                  SearchToolsVisible      : true,

                  UserCollaboration       : false,
                  CurrentUser             : 'Test user',

                  WMode                   : 'window',
                  localeChain             : '/viewer/en_US',
                  jsDirectory : '<add js directory>',
                  cssDirectory : '',
                  localeDirectory : '',
                  key : '<your key>'
              }});

  });
```

Here key parameter has to be taken from flexpaper website by getting your license.

**IMGFiles and JSONFile parameter are needed for html rendering only.**

**For flash rendering only SWFFile parameter is neeeded.**

**For html5 only PDFFile parameter is needed.**

**CurrentUser and UserCollaboration parameter is needed when user name should be displayed in annotations.**